# How can we use introJs for a particular group of element

Tags: javascript, intro.js

How can I use [IntroJs](http://introjs.com/) for different groups of element. Actually I want to use it for multiple part at same page. As per their [documentation](https://github.com/usablica/intro.js)

> For example introJs(".introduction-farm").start(); runs the
>   introduction only for elements with class='introduction-farm'

Now I tried with static id or dynamic Id but this part is not working. if I use `introJs().start();` then It will work but now if on page I  want to create three separate introduction then this method combine them into one. So anybody here able to successfully implement this. Then please share with me.

Answer (score 1):

just add data-step, data-intro and data-position attributes to the grouped divs
e.g.

```
<div class="span6" data-step="2" data-intro="Ok, wasn't that fun?" data-position='right'></div>
```

and then onclick just do introJs().start();

e.g.

```
    <a class="btn btn-large btn-success" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:introJs().start();">Show me how</a>
```

for details:

https://github.com/usablica/intro.js/blob/master/example/hello-world/index.html

Comment: Yes I know this. But if we want to use it for multiple component in same page then we can pass the classname. But I can't make it to work.